# Where to get Build status field in TFS_Warehouse

Tags: sql

Am trying to fetch build details from TFS system. However am unable to get status (success/failure/etc.) of builds from TFS_warehouse database. Can someone help to identify this column?

This field is present in TFS_Analysis (Analysis server).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

table FactBuildDetails, column BuildStatusSK